# It is all in the past

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

*Presented* here are questions *related* to past tense words I *researched* and *googled* that *resulted* in this *designed* and *developed* puzzle. *Got* it?

1. Which past tense word (PTW) is also a past tense word when read backwards? At least 1 example.
2. Two PTWs which when read backwards are simple verbs - do not include answer from 1.
3. The past tense of this verb consists of replacing 1 of its letters with 4 completely different letters.(location not important)
4. A PTW where, if you remove the last letter, you get a PTW. At least 3 examples please.
5. Start with a PTW

   - Remove first letter - you get a PTW
   - Remove first two letters - you get a PTW
   - Remove first three letters - you get a PTW
   - Remove first four letters - you get a PTW
6. A PTW that includes a verb, its past tense and its past participle, all three appearing as consecutive letters (not spaced).

No programming please.

**NO Partial Answers please**. I might relax this restriction if a complete answer is not received within a reasonable time.

Comment: For number 6, do the three distinct components (verb, past tense and past participle) need to appear with no overlap?

Comment: Are dictionaries allowed? You only forbid programming, but there is a [no-computers] tag.

Comment: Overlap is fine for 6. Dictionaries allowed.

Comment: Some puzzles make me feel tense when solving them, but this one made me feel way past tense.

Comment: @Randal'Thor LOL 10se times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1

> WAS and SAW

2

> LAID (DIAL) and TUBED (DEBUT)

3

> BU**Y** and B**O**U**GHT**

4

> BORED -> BORE
>  ROSED -> ROSE
>  [RODED](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rode) -> RODE

5

> [SCROWED](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrow) -> CROWED -> ROWED -> OWED -> WED.
>  I think you can even add one more to the beginning of this chain with ESCROWED

6

> THREATENED contains EAT, ATE and EATEN and all three of these are distinct.

Comment: I was partway through an answer, but you beat me to it. I had a potentially better one for #4: rot13(ENA & ENAT).

Comment: Rfpebjrq vf n terng svaq. V unq gur bar gung @Bass zragvbarq. Terng wbo obgu bs lbh.

Comment: @DrD Thank you, as I commented to Bass, I don't think the third word in that example is a PTW (at least not that I could find) but I understand the thinking.

Answer (score 4):

[Hexomino beat me to it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/115206/36023), so I had to redo everything. I hope I avoided any repeats.

1 Which past tense word (PTW) is also a past tense word when read backwards? At least 1 example.

> **Did**

2 Two PTWs which when read backwards are simple verbs - do not include answer from 1.

> **lived** (devil, as in eggs), **reviled** (deliver)

3 The past tense of this verb consists of replacing 1 of its letters with 4 completely different letters.(location not important)

> [do**w** / do**ught**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dought) (yeah, of course I had "buy" originally)

4 A PTW where, if you remove the last letter, you get a PTW. At least 3 examples please.

> **SPOKE**D, **FORBAD**E, **RAN**G

5 Start with a PTW, remove letters

The deceptive ranch chairman that got shot

> **stabled** the horses,
>  **tabled** the motion,
>  became differently **abled**,
>  **bled** profusely,
>  and **led** us astray.

6 A PTW that includes a verb, its past tense and its past participle, all three appearing as consecutive letters (not spaced).

Stupid answer (but only because I couldn't think of a better one):

> **bet**. (bet/bet/bet)

Comment: So in your example for 4 would you consider the third word as a PTW because I would have said it is an adjective (I only say this as I was tempted by this string of words myself)?

Comment: Hmm, you are probably right. I was thinking along the lines of symmetry with "disabled", but since the word is a recent euphemism, if probably comes from absolutely nowhere.

Comment: Amusing and great answers @Bass, except the last one :)